# NSURLConnection and initializing data object

Tags: objective-c, json, object, nsurlconnection

I have an iOS app that pulls JSON from a remote PHP file and displays that data in a table. When I use my database/JSON file, a piece of code won't run. However, when I use a tutorial's database (http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/) it works fine. I have used the exact code in the tutorial, the JSON looks the exact same, and the PHP works fine. How can I fix this?

Objective-C

```
#import "HomeModel.h"
#import "Location.h"

@interface HomeModel()
{
    NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation HomeModel

- (void)downloadItems
{
    // Download the json file
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"192.168.0.4/service.php"];
    NSLog(@"Donwload the JSON file");

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];
    NSLog(@"Create the request");

    // Create the NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Create the NSURLConnection");
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse      *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Inititalize the data object");

    // Initialize the data object
    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the newly downloaded data
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Create an array to store the locations
    NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
        newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"Name"];
        newLocation.address = jsonElement[@"Address"];
        newLocation.latitude = jsonElement[@"Latitude"];
        newLocation.longitude = jsonElement[@"Longitude"];

        // Add this question to the locations array
        [_locations addObject:newLocation];
    }

    // Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
    if (self.delegate)
     {
       [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
    }
}

@end
```

EDIT: After further analysis, everything before `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse      *)response` works. When this piece of code comes next, nothing happens.
`

Comment: There are lots of possible problems, and you really should narrow it down for us by debugging this app, single stepping through the offending routines, and find out where it's failing. You have to narrow this down for us.

Comment: That notwithstanding, did you implement `connection:didFailWithError:` in order to detect `NSURLConnection` errors? Check the `NSError` object that returns, if any. Are you even getting to `connectionDidFinishLoading`? If so, is `jsonArray` a `nil` value or not? If it's `nil`, did you check the `NSError` object returned by `JSONObjectWithData`.

Comment: The code won't run?  It looks like it runs a little. Can you fix this question with nslogs of the json when it runs well and when it doesn't, and with a description of "won't run"?

Comment: Fixed it! In the URLWithString, I had to have http://192.168.0.4/service.php instead.